# Cannot return null from a non-@Nullable @Provides method

Tags: java, android, null

I have injected `clientProvider` like this into my class:

```
 @Inject
    public DepictDao(@Named("depicts") Provider<ContentProviderClient> clientProvider) {
        this.clientProvider = clientProvider;
    }
```

However I received an error which says:

```
Cannot return null from a non-@Nullable @Provides method
```

when i tried to call

```
ContentProviderClient db = clientProvider.get();
```

Comment: So ... have you check that your inject actually works?

Comment: not sure how to check

Comment: You should add  `@Provides ContentProviderClient contentProviderClient(){ return new ContentProviderClientImpl(); }`  inside your guice module. Basically you have to write provider for that class somewhere in your module. It could be helpful if you add the module file too.

Comment: This exist on my common module

Comment: ``` @Provides
    @Named("depicts")
    public ContentProviderClient provideDepictsContentProviderClient(Context context) {
        return context.getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient(BuildConfig.DEPICTS_AUTHORITY);
    }```